# Why is there a double call in this React function?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Below I've included the relevant code. You can see the page in action at https://nextflix-96831.web.app (sign in with google then hit the like or dislike button). Basically, whenever you hit the like or dislike button, data is pulled from the database twice with the first data immediately being replaced by the second data.

I think this has something to do with my `setRender`, but I'm not sure since I'm new to react.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import './Menu/Menu.css';

function RateMovies() {

    const popularMoviesRef = firebase.database().ref("/popular_movies");
    const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = React.useState([]);
    var [render, setRender] = React.useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        popularMoviesRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
            
            var newArray = []
    
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var data = childSnapshot.val();

                newArray.push({ 
                    movieTitle: data.movie_title, 
                    moviePoster: data.movie_poster, 
                })
            });

            setPopularMovies([...popularMovies, ...newArray])
        });
    }, [render]);


    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
    var movie = popularMovies[index];
    console.log(movie);

    const auth = firebase.auth();
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var user_id = auth.currentUser.uid;

    function likedMovie() {

        var genres = movie.movieGenre.split(',');

        db.collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
            "Rated.liked": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                movieTitle: movie.movieTitle, 
                moviePoster: movie.moviePoster, 
             })})
        .then(function(){
            setRender(render + 1);
        });

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
        movie = popularMovies[index];
    }
    
    
    return (
        <div class="rate-background">
            <div className="rate-title"> {movie?.movieTitle} </div>
            <button onClick={likedMovie}> Like</button>
            <img class="rate-image" src={`${movie?.moviePoster}`} />
        </div>
    )
  
  } 

  export default RateMovies;
```

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to replace the [render] at the end of the useEffect with [0]

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with:

```
setPopularMovies([...popularMovies, ...newArray])
```

Try removing `...popularMovies` and have it like:

```
setPopularMovies([newArray])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything at all